# Easier Way To Scrape This Difficult Site?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab Player Name and the FP column from [here](http://www.numberfire.com/nba/daily-fantasy/daily-basketball-projections). Usually when I need table info I could load it up into a `Dataframe` using `pandas` or at least run a `find_all()` method with `bs4`. I found one page that recommended something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scrape_url ='http://www.numberfire.com/nba/fantasy/full-fantasy-basketball-projections'
page = requests.get(scrape_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

script = soup.find('script', text=lambda x: x and 'NF_DATA' in x).text
data = re.search(r'NF_DATA = (.*?);', script).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)
print(data)
```

But that didn't work, if anyone has some guidance I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a good question.

First of all, before diving into the solution, make sure to study the ["Terms of Service"](http://www.numberfire.com/info/terms-of-service) and understand if you are allowed to scrape the resource this way, be a good [web-scraping citizen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette).

---

The problem is, the site checks if you are authenticated and, if not, it would set the `NF_DATA` to something like:

```
{u'is_logged_in': False, u'FACEBOOK_APP_NAMESPACE': u'numberfire', u'FACEBOOK_APP_ID': u'103292676390270'}
```

But, if you open the page in the browser while not being authenticated or would study the `page.content`, you would see that *the desired data is actually there in the HTML* - you can scrape it directly, no need to go through parsing the `script` tag contents.

Getting `fp` ratings is a little bit tricky - they are separated from the actual "player" table, but, we can "connect" them together by using the `data-player-id` unique attribute. First, we parse the `fp` ratings and construct a "player_id" -> "fp value" dictionary. Then, go through the "player" table, scrape the rest of the information and look up the dictionary containing the `fp` values.

**Implementation:**

```
# parse fp ratings
ratings = {player['data-player-id']: player.select_one(".fp.active").get_text(strip=True)
           for player in soup.select("table.projection-table.no-fix tr[data-player-id]")}

# parse player info
for player in soup.select("table.projection-table.projection-table--fixed tr[data-player-id]"):
    player_name = player.select_one(".player-info a.full").get_text(strip=True)
    fp_rating = ratings.get(player['data-player-id'])

    print(player_name, fp_rating)
```

Prints:

```
(u'Russell Westbrook', u'55.1')
(u'Anthony Davis', u'49.3')
(u'DeMarcus Cousins', u'48.9')
(u'James Harden', u'48.4')
(u'LeBron James', u'48.3')
...
(u'Tim Hardaway Jr.', u'0.0')
(u'Kyle Korver', u'0.0')
(u'Dwight Howard', u'0.0')
(u'Reggie Williams', u'0.0')
```

Note the use of [CSS selector `select()` and `select_one()` methods](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).